# Use HTML formatting inside xml tags in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

this is my xml snippet:

```
<description><div>Why did you make this request?</div> </description>
```

The code is generated from a CRM, so I cannot change it to my will. The field 'description' in the CRM has a WYSIWYG editor, this is why (I think) in the plain XML it prints the  tags.

How can I edit the XSLT below, so that the pdf output either uses the html notation to format the text, or completely ignores it? This is my XSLT line:

```
<fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="testBorderLeft">
    <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="/hash/description"/></fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is a "name code"? Can you give an example of a "name code" and its corresponding symbol?

Comment: @JLRishe '&#63;' that stands for '?' or '&nbsp' for non-breaking space, maybe I should have just called it HTML code?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I updated the question, taking out the part about the ampersands, because it was a preference issue in the CRM that has been fixed now. So, I just need to get rid of the html tags. Just to be clear, can you confirm that it cannot be done?

Comment: In your current edit, the code should work and create a `fo:block` with the plain text inside of the description.

Comment: @MartinHonnen my current code prints this out <div>Why did you make this request?</div> on the PDF, also if people make the test bold in the editor, the pdf print out the <strong> tags for example

Comment: In that your XML is rather `<description><![CDATA[<div>Why did you make this request?</div> ]]></description>`  and not `<description><div>Why did you make this request?</div> </description>`. You haven't told in any way which XSLT processor on which platform you use. XSLT 3 with `parse-xml` and/or `parse-xml-fragment` can parsed markup, depending the XSLT processor and edition there might also be extension functions to parse markup and process it further to e.g. strip elements or transform them to XSL-FO. In XSLT 2 or 3 you can also use David Carlisle's XSLT 2 implementation of an HTML parser

Comment: @MartinHonnen I apologize, I am really trying to figure this out, since it's really not my cup of tea, but it kinda has fallen into my lap at work anyway. I am sure that it uses XSLT 1.0, I am not sure what you mean by platform though (the name of the CRM?).
Also, the only way I have to access the XML file is by changing the extension of the PDF download file into .XML, and what I see is not `<description><![CDATA[<div>Why did you make this request?</div> ]]></description>` but rather `<description><div>Why did you make this request?</div> </description>` so that's what I posted.

Comment: In my view the HTML markup, to show up as plain text in your PDF, must be escaped in the XML, either as I have shown as a CDATA section or perhaps with entity references. At https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcxG you can see that no HTML markup is output with value-of if the input is as you show.

Comment: The question about the platform means Java or .NET or PHP so that perhaps there is a way to plugin in an extension function. But if all the XSLT use is hidden inside of some CRM you probably don't have access to APIs. Perhaps add a tag for the CRM to the question if StackOverflow has one so that other users see it and might be able to help.